# Why does the whole integral converge but not part of it? (Dilogs)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, special-functions

$\newcommand{\Li}{\operatorname{Li}}$Consider the integral:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(-\Li_2(x) - \Li_3(x) - x^2/8 + 3x - x\log(1-x) + \log(1-x))}{x^2} \, dx$$

This integral converges to $\sim 0.01$

But when taken separately,

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{-\Li_2(x) - \Li_3(x)}{x^2} \, dx$$

this integral **does not converge.**

What is going on here? I dont understand?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty (x-x) dx$ converges but $\int_0^\infty x dx$ does not. Is that unexpected?

Comment: I don't know the specifics in regard to this _particular_ integral, but it's pretty easy to construct examples in which $\int_0^1 (f(x)+g(x))\,dx$ converges and $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ does not.  The way you phrased your question makes it seem as if you find _that_ paradoxical. But all you need to do is find a case where $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ diverges to $\infty$ and then figure out what $g(x)$ has to be so that it cancels out the "bad" part of $f(x) + g(x)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thanks. Then how can I compute the first, complicated integral without splitting it up?

Comment: @Amad27 You could start by subtracting out the simpler convergent terms (most obviously the third term).

Comment: @DavidH, the problem is the polylogarithms, how can we evaluate an integral so that the polylogs converge/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

After subtracting out the quadratic term in the numerator, we're left with three terms in the numerator whose power series expansions each begin with a $-x$ we need to somehow cancel, plus $3x$. The key is then distributing these three $x$'s to pair up with one these other terms and then we may split the sum:

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{3x-\frac{x^2}{8}+\left(1-x\right)\ln{\left(1-x\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac18+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{3x+\left(1-x\right)\ln{\left(1-x\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac18+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x+\left(1-x\right)\ln{\left(1-x\right)}+x-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}+x-\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac18+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x+\left(1-x\right)\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(x\right)}}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x.\\
\end{align}$$